# Why is there use null-forgiving operator?

Tags: c#, .net-core

There is FindIndex method in System.Array class,Net Core 3.0. I don't understand why is there use `!` if the `match` parameter doesn't have `?` operator and we don't get compiler warning?

```cs
public static int FindIndex<T>(T[] array, int startIndex, int count, Predicate<T> match)
        {
            //
           ...
            //
            if (match == null)
            {
                ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.match);
            }

            int endIndex = startIndex + count;
            for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
            {
                if (match!(array[i])) <--- 
                    return i;
            }
            return -1;
        }
```

Comment: The latest sources show that there is no `!` operator https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Array.cs,52500131cc2a645d Null forgiving operator doesn't make sense here, because you are checking the `match` to `null` earlier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will no see this operator in the lates source code, but if your try to check git blame on github page, you can see small comment: [Array.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blame/0d0a89a736664b635a8edcb739e613a337bd429c/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Array.cs)

> // TODO-NULLABLE: Remove ! when [DoesNotReturn] respected

Then if you look closer on this code:

```
if (match == null)
{
    ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.match);
}
```

And compare it to:

```
if (match == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(match));
}
```

You can see that it check for `null` and then throws an exception (it is done by helper method `ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException`), but compiler does not know that this method will "interrupt" the execution of `FindIndex` method when `match` is `null` (because `[DoesNotReturn]` attribute is not implemented yet). So, the compiler will generate an error, because it will think that `match` is still can be `null`, and we need to force compiler to ignore it. Later, the attribute was implemented and `!` operator was removed. ([Source code of helper method](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/ThrowHelper.cs#L210))

Comment: thank you for the answer, but why does the compiler generate an error? ```match ``` parameter doesn't have ```?``` operator

Comment: @EvgeniyTerekhin please see https://gist.github.com/sys27/7f99836911a3a174b619a68032cdcaaf

Comment: @EvgeniyTerekhin it happens because we check for `null` and compiler understand that it is null already and show warning (not error I was wrong, but probably corefx threat warnings as errors) then we try to access null object (it does not understand that helper method will throw exception and never return a result)

Comment: thank you very much. I tried this case and most likely were inattentive. According to your gist, I got a warning)